# Ngx Bootstrap Popover to display only one popover at a time

Tags: angular, frontend, angular5, popover, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using angular to make a popover only appear once at a time this is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NMjeFv5li5zWe6drBgD2?p=preview) I'm using angular5 with Ngx-Bootstrap.

Because I have multiple popover that I need in my project however the popover should only close if we press the (x) at the top right.

The toggle currently works with 2 popover provided if you press the toggle button first and then the press "Pop over with title and a x button!"
My objective is to disable the other popover, if a popover is currently open.

Example there is 4 popover, popover 1-4. 
if popover 1 is open no other popover can be open.

The other popover can be open provided we close popover 1.

```html
<div>
  <ng-template #popoverContent3>
    <div style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-weight:bold;">
      <p>this is a title...
      <button type="button" (click)='pop2.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>The best looking pop over, with a TITLE!</p>  
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <a  [popover]="popoverContent3" #pop2="bs-popover" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" [outsideClick]="false"  placement="right">
   Pop over with title and a x button!
    </a>
</div>
<p>
  <span popover="Hello there! I was triggered by input"
        triggers=""  [isOpen]="isOpen">
  This text has attached popover
  </span>
</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
  Toggle
</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to see only one opened popover at a time, it can be achieved via `ViewChildren` and `onShown`.

The algorithm is something like this:

1) Listen to all `onShown` events

2) Close all other popovers

```
@ViewChildren(PopoverDirective) popovers: QueryList<PopoverDirective>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.popovers.forEach((popover: PopoverDirective) => {
    popover.onShown.subscribe(() => {
      this.popovers
      .filter(p => p !== popover)
      .forEach(p => p.hide());
    });
  });
}
```

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz?file=app%2Ffour-directions.ts

Comment: Yes thats the solution I need however it's not working in my project and my plunker . Do we have to install some additional features?
https://plnkr.co/edit/NPVqrI9aFZRXJhsWRmMj?p=preview  @llya Surmay

Comment: I'm getting this error on my project
localhost/:54 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:8080/Scripts/libs/ngx-bootstrap/popover.js, I'm able to use the stackblitz codes with angular alone but it seems there seems to be problem with visual studio

Comment: Perhaps this is happening because of imports. If you're using `system.js` (plunkr uses it), then you have to import popover from `ngx-bootstrap`, not `ngx-bootstrap/popover`

Comment: Yup, I'm using systemjs, in my system.js I'm doing this, 

map:{
'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap/'
},
packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            },
            //rxjs: {
            //    defaultExtension: false
            //},
            'ngx-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        },
I'm already  importing ngx-bootstrap not ngx-bootstrap/popover isn't it?

Comment: I understand what u mean it is working now thank you very much!!

Comment: how to open pop over using ng if?